# Get all prime numbers up to a point

Tags: java

I currently have this code, but when I input a number (such as 20) it returns -1, any ideas why this might be happening? Thank you

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> prime(int num){

    ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> nul = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    nul.add(-1);

        for(int i = 1; i < num; i++) {
            for(int j = 2; j < i - 1; j++){
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    return nul;
                }
                primes.add(i);
            }
        }
    return primes;
}
```

Comment: Why do you `return nul;`?

Comment: because your code logic is wrong. where is the code to check whether number is prime ?

Comment: I couldnt find a way to express that the inputed number had no primes so I created an array called nul that contained -1 lol (im new)

Comment: Please make an effort to debug your own code, as Stackoverflow is not a website for you to dump your code and have problems solved for you. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for the sort of questions that are on topic for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `-1` because you are returning `nul`, the moment your if the condition is getting `true`. In such scenario you should be using `continue`, and here it will resolve your issue but create another one i.e. using it here will result in duplicate entries in yours list.

So, I suggest you to use a `boolean flag` variable along with `break` to give you your desired result. Below is a code snippet with added comments for explanation

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> prime(int num){
    ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> nul = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    nul.add(-1);
        boolean flag=true;
        for(int i = 1; i < num; i++) {
            flag=true;
            for(int j = 2; j < i; j++){
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    flag=false;  // set it to false, if number is not prime
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(flag) {           // If flag was true till this point
                primes.add(i);   // means it is current number is prime. so add it to list
            }
        }
    return primes;
}
```